# canvasses aren't staying inside div

Tags: html, css, canvas

Hy,

I have the following problem: I have a parent div, within that an image and three canvasses. The canvasses are laying on top of each other, which should, but the canvasses are laying next to the parent div and the image. To illustrate my problem, here is an image of how it looks like now: [image: Checkers.png].

As you see, the three canvases with the checker pieces and two other canvasses used for drawing on top of those pieces, aren't laying on top of the checkerboard.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="checkerboard" class="checkerboard">
    <img src="../images/checkerboard.png">
    <canvas id="canvas_checkers" class="canvas_checkers" width="650" height="650"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas_checkers_mouse" class="canvas_checkers" width="650" height="650"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas_checkers_selected" class="canvas_checkers" width="650" height="650"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="chat">
    <ul id="chatlist">

    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 1254px;
    height: 650px;
    margin: auto;
}

#chat {
    width: 300px;
    height: 650px;
    background: rgb(140, 140, 140);
    float: right;
}

#checkerboard {
    width: 654;
    height: 650;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.canvas_checkers{
    float: left;
    width: 650px;
    height: 650px;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

I hope I made myself clear

Zeno

Answer (score 0):

You can make the image absolutely positioned, so you can layer it together with the canvases using z-index.

However, I'd strongly suggest that you put a background image on the `#checkerboard` element instead of using a separate image. Like this:

HTML

```
<div id="checkerboard" class="checkerboard">
    <canvas id="canvas_checkers" class="canvas_checkers" width="650" height="650"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas_checkers_mouse" class="canvas_checkers" width="650" height="650"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas_checkers_selected" class="canvas_checkers" width="650" height="650"></canvas>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#checkerboard {background-image: url("../images/checkerboard.png");}
```